# Why can't my client connect to my server?

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine, flask, braintree

I have an android client and a server which should talk to each other. I am using flask and hosting my server on app engine. Here is the `main.py` file:

```
from flask import Flask
import braintree

braintree.Configuration.configure(braintree.Environment.Sandbox,
                                  merchant_id="something_censored",
                                  public_key="something_censored",
                                  private_key="something_censored")

app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

@app.route('/<name>')
def hello_name(name):
    return "Howdy {}".format(name)


@app.route('/client_token', methods=["GET"])
def client_token():
    return braintree.ClientToken.generate()

@app.route('/create_customer/<firstName>/<lastName>/<email>', methods=["GET"])
def create_customer(firstName, lastName, email):
    result = braintree.Customer.create({
        "first_name": firstName,
        "last_name": lastName,
        "email": email,
    })
    return result.customer.id


@app.route('/create_payment_method_for_customer/<customerId>/<clientNonce>', methods=["POST"])
def create_payment_method_for_customer(customerId, clientNonce):
    braintree.PaymentMethod.create({
        "customer_id": customerId,
        "payment_method_nonce": clientNonce,
        "options": {
            "verify_card": True,
            "verification_merchant_account_id": "ydt4s72wzw46wdbs",
            "verification_amount": "0.00",
        }
    })

@app.route('/get_customer_payment_methods/<customer_id>')
def get_customer_payment_methods(customer_id):
    result = braintree.Customer.find(customer_id)
    return result.payment_methods
```

I have downloaded the braintree server sdk in python using the `pip install braintree` command and I have installed the 2.7 python app engine sdk.
After having deployed my flask server hosted on app engine at http://birthpayserver.appspot.com/ I make a call to the '/client_token' route like so:

```
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
            .scheme("http")
            .authority("www.birthpayserver.appspot.com")
            .appendPath("create_customer")
            .appendPath(firstName)
            .appendPath(lastName)
            .appendPath(email);
    String url = builder.build().toString();

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get(url, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String customerId) {
            mCustomerId = customerId;
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Failed to create account, try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, responseString);
        }
    });
```

The `onFailure` method is called and the `responseString` is equal to this:

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>500 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Server Error</h1>
<h2>The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
```

When I run my server the log is the following:

```
INFO     2016-08-07 13:07:23,435 sdk_update_checker.py:229] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2016-08-07 13:07:24,348 sdk_update_checker.py:257] The SDK is up to date.
WARNING  2016-08-07 13:07:24,547 simple_search_stub.py:1146] Could not read search indexes from /var/folders/vv/4vyp0dmd5fl0v7n7pgmj0kyc0000gn/T/appengine.birthpayserver.tomfinet/search_indexes
INFO     2016-08-07 13:07:24,551 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:54454
INFO     2016-08-07 13:07:24,556 api_server.py:648] Applying all pending transactions and saving the datastore
INFO     2016-08-07 13:07:24,556 api_server.py:651] Saving search indexes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 89, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 85, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 1040, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 1033, in main
    dev_server.start(options)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 824, in start
    self._dispatcher.start(options.api_host, apis.port, request_data)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/dispatcher.py", line 194, in start
    _module.start()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py", line 1177, in start
    self._balanced_module.start()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_server.py", line 315, in start
    self._start_all_fixed_port(host_ports)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_server.py", line 352, in _start_all_fixed_port
    raise BindError('Unable to bind %s:%s' % self.bind_addr)
google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.wsgi_server.BindError: Unable to bind 127.0.0.1:8080

Process finished with exit code 1
```

EDIT:

When running my flask server again the log says that there is an `ImportError: No module named braintree`, however I have installed braintree.

How do I make the server run on app engine so that it accepts and responds to `http` requests?

Comment: `starting API server at: http://localhost:54454`. Better use the LAN ip of the machine. How testing with browser on same machine?

Comment: That does not solve the braintree import problem.